# Rails nested resource routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, nested-resources

I have a routing error with a nested resource.  Here is my nested routing:

```
resources :users do
  resources :pages
end
```

This is my minitest "visit new user page" system test:

```
test "visit new user page path" do
  user = User.create
  visit new_user_page_path(user)
  assert_selector "h1", text: "Page"
end
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Error:
PagesTest#test_visit_new_user_page_path:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `pages_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007fa0299dfa28>:0x00007fa02aa23df8>
Did you mean?  image_path
app/views/pages/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_pages__form_html_erb__3658586168370814469_70162960780560'
app/views/pages/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_pages_new_html_erb__3548077654233884011_70162934875400'
```

**I realize that *pages_path* is not a correct path for this nested resource**.  The correct path to *pages#new* is *new_user_page_path(@user)* (which is the path that took me to *new.html.erb*). The correct path to *pages#create* is a POST to *user_pages_path(@user)* (which is the page that *new.html.erb* should POST to).  But I cannot find anywhere that **pages_path** is being called.  The error says that it is being called in *new.html.erb* and also *_form.html.erb*.  Here are those pages.  First, new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New Page</h1>

<%= render 'form', page: @page %>
<%= link_to 'Back', user_pages_path(@page) %>
```

And _form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_with(model: page, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if page.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(page.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this page from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% page.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :title %>
    <%= form.text_field :title, id: :page_title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :content %>
    <%= form.text_area :content, id: :page_content %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.text_field :user_id, id: :page_user_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I don't know where **pages_path** is being called, so I can't fix that error.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your form code, page_path is called from it. Should be

```
<%= form_with(model: [ @user, @page ]) do |form| %>
```

In this case the route will be set correctly.

Comment: Thanks Vasilisa.  I was so focused on thinking it was a routing problem, I did not realize it was really a form helper problem.  Ugh!  ;-(